# Preventing website pages from being appended with '?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1' and creating a Stripe issue

Tags: asp.net, webforms, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am working on an ASP.NET WebForms application, and when I launch the site in my browser, this is what shows up in the address bar:

`https://localhost:44358/home.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1`

The problem is, the '?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1' portion of the address is causing a problem with my Stripe webhandler when I am trying to test it.  When I launch the Stripe CLI and trigger the `payment_intent.succeeded` event, I get this:

[image: Stripe CLI output]

From what I see, this is saying there's a redirect, and the webhook code never executes.  I checked the Stripe webhook log, and here's what I see:

[image: Stripe webhook event log]

For whatever reason, and I don't know how, the '?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1' part is being added to the webhook's address, so Stripe sees it as a redirect and the webhook doesn't fire.

From what I found, the solution to this issue, removing the '?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1' portion of the URL string, SHOULD be easy to fix fix by using `cookieless='UseCookies'` in my web.config file, and this seems to work when the site is loaded into the browser.  But for whatever reason, that part of the string is still being appended to the webhook when the .ashx file is called.

I spent half a day trying to resolve this with no luck.  Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: if you made this change, and don't see the cookie setting in the URL when browsing? Then this is a browser cache issue. Clear out your browser's cache and cookies and try again....

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out (finally!).  In my web.config file I have an `<anonymousIdentification>` element further down in the file from the `<forms>` element, and I still had `cookieless="AutoDetect"` set.  Once I updated this to `"UseCookies"` everything worked as it should.

REALLY stupid of me!